# How to attach Fragments to NavigationAppBar(Material Design 2.0)

Tags: android, material-design

There are sentence "This can be coordinated with a Fragment transition to allow for a smooth animation from a primary screen to a secondary screen." on googles Material Design site [BottomAppBar page](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/)

Who ever figured it out how to attach smooth animation to fragments when appBottomBar alignment mode changed?

Comment: That passage in the docs is referring to `FloatingActionButton`. What does that have to do with "... how to attach smooth animation to fragments when appBottomBar.."?

Comment: Yes, but FloatingActionButton section also includes this sentence without any explanations how to use fragments with BottomAppBar